# Creating a DOM element from a Handlebars template using jQuery not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

This is the handlebars template:

```
  <div class="cnbody">
<div class="cnhead">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="cncontent">
        <div id="horizontalTab">
            <ul>
                {{#if head.length}}
                    {{#each head}}
                        <li><a href="#{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                {{/if}}
            </ul>
            <div id="{{body.details.link}}">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    {{#if body.details.content.length}}
                        {{#each body.details.content}}
                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">{{name}}</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">{{value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                    {{/if}}         
                </table>
            </div>
            {{#if body.tabs.length}}
                {{#each body.tabs}}
                    <div id="{{link}}">
                        <ul class="cntbs">
                            {{#if content.length}}
                                {{#each content}}
                                    {{#if tCode}}
                                        <li><a href="#{{link}}" data-tcode="{{tCode}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                                        {{else}}
                                            <li><a href="#{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>       
                                    {{/if}}
                                {{/each}}
                            {{/if}}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            {{/if}} 
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the [requirejs handlebars plugin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) to compile the template:

```
    var tabsHtml=tabs(tabsData);
```

This returns a string that looks like this:

```
       <div class="cnbody">
<div class="cnhead">Sample Heading</div>
    <div class="cncontent">
        <div id="horizontalTab">
            <ul>


                        <li><a href="#tab-1">Sample details</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#tab-2">Sample Actions 1</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#tab-3">Sample Actions 2</a></li>


            </ul>
            <div id="tab-1">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">


                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Sample Type</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%"></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Sample Key</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%"></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Sample Key 2</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">fsifsfnds</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" height="25">Stuff</td>
                                <td width="10%">:</td>
                                <td width="45%">More Stuff</td>
                            </tr>


                </table>
            </div>


                    <div id="tab-2">
                        <ul class="cntbs">



                                            <li><a href="#openModal">Create</a></li>        



                                            <li><a href="#openModal">Delete</a></li>        



                                            <li><a href="#openModal">Multiple</a></li>      



                                            <li><a href="#openModal">Display</a></li>       



                                            <li><a href="#openModal">Update</a></li>        



                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab-3">
                        <ul class="cntbs">



                                        <li><a href="##" data-tcode="XYZ">Create</a></li>



                                            <li><a href="##">Delete</a></li>        



                                        <li><a href="##" data-tcode="XYZ2">Multiple</a></li>



                                        <li><a href="##" data-tcode="XYZ3">Display</a></li>



                                        <li><a href="##" data-tcode="IE02">Update</a></li>



                        </ul>
                    </div>


        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I try to create a jQuery element with this which fails in IE7 but works in Chrome:

```
  var $tabs=$(tabsHtml);
```

I try to use `$tabs.get(0)` and it returns `undefined`

Comment: What kind of error IE7 is returning? Where is the template going to be put? Is it in a table by chance?

Comment: @MarcoCI IE7 returns no error but `$tabs.get(0)` is undefined.This gets put inside a google maps InfoWindow

Comment: Is `$tabs` actually defined?

Comment: @MarcoCI Yes,`$tabs` is initialized based on the template,it exists,it works perfectly in `Chrome`

Comment: What's its content in IE7? Just print it as a string in a div.

Comment: @MarcoCI The string is in the third code block and represents the result of passing a context to the handlebars template in the first code block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56526/discussion-between-marcoci-and-user2309862).